# how to load nested relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have 3 models that i want to start from a and load the relation with b and i want to load the relation betwen b and c there in a too is that possible ?? here is what i want to do in code :

```
AccommodationRoomModel which is the B model:
public function accommodation(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Accommodation::class);
    }

  public function roomPricingHistory(){
    return $this->hasMany(RoomPricingHistory::class);
}
```

and in The accomodation model :

```
public function accommodationRoom()
{
    return $this->Hasmany(AccommodationRoom::class);
}
```

and finaly in the room pricingHistory :

```
 public function accommodationRoom(){
    return $this->belongsTo(AccommodationRoom::class);
}
```

now in my accomodation controller i want to get All the accomodation with the room and from room i want to get the price so here is it

```
A = Accomodation
B = Room
C = price
```

and i want to call somehow like this

```
From A get B and The relation Of it with C and show all in A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravels nested eager loading for this:

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For
>   example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the
>   author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:

```php
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

In your case:

```php
$accomodations = Accomodation::with('accommodationRoom.roomPricingHistory')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

[nested-eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

A::with('B.C');